# В чем отличие виртуальной среды Anaconda от venv или virtualenv?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, venv, ipython

Вопрос о виртуальных средах. Хотелось бы узнать, в чем их отличие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В том, что venv и virtualenv - это инструменты (модули) для создания и поддержки виртуальных сред. А Anaconda - это  сборка, куда входят дистрибутив языков программирования Python и R, набор популярных библиотек (что-то порядка 2К, практически всех, которые потребуются новичку в первые пару лет работы) ,  и несколько IDE (среди них Spyder,PyCharm, Visual Studio Code и Jupyter Notebook)

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. 
У Anaconda есть команда, для создания виртуальной среды, например Python 3.6: 
`conda create -n virt1 python=3.6`
Потому я и задал такой вопрос. Видимо нет никакого отличия.